# Ubuntu on Macmini8,1 not booting

Tags: boot, system-installation, mac, mac-mini

I am attempting to install 20.10 to a Mac mini that I have (Macmini8,1 aka "Late 2018"), and seem to be unable to. I'm installing what I would expect is the simplest scenario:

- I'm installing to the sole internal drive
- I'm letting the installer take the whole drive
- There is no other OS that I'm trying to dual boot with

What I've tried so far:

- Booting from the live desktop USB, and selecting "Install Ubuntu" seems to work without issue.
- Booting from the live desktop USB, and selecting "Try Ubuntu" and then launching the installer in the booted environment seems to work
- Booting and installing from the live server USB also seems to work

After installing, in all of these cases, rebooting just leads me to a flashing question mark and the Mac acts as if it has no OS installed on it. Rebooting into the live installer shows that, at least according to the installer, the previous install is there on disk (as it offers to reinstall, erase, or install alongside the existing installation as additional options).

Comment: The newer the Apple product the more likely it wont run Ubuntu due to certain chips Apple uses in their products.

Comment: Then how is the live USB able to boot without issue?

Comment: It simply can not work on some new Apple products.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; the live image *does* work (it boots, I can see the internal drive, networking, etc.). What's different about the installed OS vs the OS that comes on the live image such that one boots and the other doesn't?

Comment: Did you select to download updates during the install?

Comment: I've installed both with and without downloading updates, as well as with and without 3rd party drivers. Same result each time

Comment: a probable difference is how boot/EFI is handled from the "actual partitions" in the SSD, which differs from a live boot in removable media

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit late, but anyway: you can probably get it to boot properly by using [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#linux), which will work together with grub to properly find what's bootable in the disk.